# Seg fault when calling a function

Tags: c++, c, segmentation-fault

My program experiences a seg fault in the middle of the loop iteration. After calling the function intermediate, the `inter_value` prints until `inter_value[199][208]`, and then, I have a seg fault.
To make sure it is not out of bound access, I print the array `inter_value` first and the array prints without any problem.

Is this a symbol of running out of memory? The array `ct` and `inter_value` are created by `malloc`, `key_byte` is a static array.

```
D = 200;
K = 256;
for(j = 0; j < D; j++)
    for(i = 0; i < K; i++)
        printf("inter_value[%i][%i] = %i\n", j, i, inter_value[j][i]);

for(j = 0; j < D; j++) {
    for(i = 0; i < K; i++) {
        intermediate(ct[j][0], key_byte[i], &inter_value[j][i]);
        printf("inter_value[%i][%i] = %i\n", j, i, inter_value[j][i]);
        fflush(stdout);
    }
}
printf("rex\n");


for(j = 0; j < D; j++) {
    for(i = 0; i < K; i++) {
        hamming_dist(ct[j][0], inter_value[j][i], &h[j][i]);
    }
}
```

Function intermediate is here

```
void intermediate(unsigned char ct, unsigned char key_byte, unsigned char *inter_value){
    *inter_value = getSBoxInvert(ct^key_byte);
}
```

---

Edit 1: Declaration of arrays.

```
//initialize different intermediate values
inter_value = (unsigned char**)malloc(D * sizeof(unsigned char*));
if(inter_value == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
    return 0;
}
for(i = 0; i < D; i++){
    inter_value[i] = (unsigned char *)malloc(K * sizeof(unsigned char)); // this is fix to key size
    if(inter_value[i] == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
        return 0;
    }
}


//ct = malloc(row * sizeof(unsigned char*));
ct = (unsigned char**)malloc(D * sizeof(unsigned char*));
if(ct == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
    return 0;
}
for(i = 0; i < D; i++){
    //ct[i] = malloc(column * sizeof(unsigned char));
    ct[i] = (unsigned char *)malloc(column * sizeof(unsigned char));
    if(ct[i] == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
        return 0;
    }
}

unsigned char key_byte[256] = {0};
```

Edit 2: The print out before seg fault.

```
inter_value[199][233] = 214
inter_value[199][234] = 119
inter_value[199][2
```

Edit 3: gdb output (It seems it is pointing to another function)

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0804a3f5 in hamming_dist (ct=31 '\037', inter_value=203 '\313', h=0x2) at cpa.cpp:53
53      *h = c;

Edit 4: After issue backtrace command from gdb...

#0  0x0804a3f5 in hamming_dist (ct=31 '\037', inter_value=203 '\313', h=0x2) at cpa.cpp:53

#1  0x0804aff5 in main (argc=3, argv=0xbffff2f4) at cpa.cpp:266

Edit 5: Add the hamming_dist function call and a printf call before it.

Edit 6: Initialization of h

```
int **h;
h = (unsigned int**)malloc(D * sizeof(unsigned int*));
if(h == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
    return 0;
}
for(i = 0; i < D; i++){
    h[i] = (unsigned int*)malloc(K * sizeof(unsigned int)); // this is fix to key size
    if(h[i] == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Edit 7: The hamming_dist function declaration.

```
void hamming_dist(unsigned char ct, unsigned char inter_value, int *h){
    int temp;
    temp = ct ^ inter_value;
    //then count No. of ones
    int c; // c accumulates the total bits set in v
    for (c = 0; temp; c++)
        temp &= temp - 1; // clear the least significant bit set

    *h = c;
}
```

Comment: Printing the value is not sufficient to prove that you are not accessing out-of-bounds.  How is `inter_value` declared?

Comment: Please show the declarations of all your arrays.

Comment: How do you allocate the `inter_value` array? Show us the `malloc` call.

Comment: present a minimal complete example that exhibits the problem, please

Comment: Make sure that your printfs are being flushed. And for Ritchie's sake, use a debugger!

Comment: The program may be crashing well after the point it prints out [199][208], since printf() is buffered.  Try using fprintf(stderr,...) or else call fflush(stdout) after each printf() call.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth, added declaration.

Comment: Or, if using a POSIX system, call `setbuf( stdin, NULL)` or `setvbuf(stdin, NULL, _IOLBF, 100)` or make sure the output is going to a terminal.

Comment: @Cheers and hth. I added the print out before the program crash.

Comment: @phonetagger, I added fflush(stdout), and it finish printing the entire matrix then it crashes.

Comment: 'inter_value[199][2' -- *definitely* a matter of unflushed printf. *Please* follow both of my suggestions ... you will save yourself and the rest of us a lot of effort.

Comment: 'it finish printing the entire matrix then it crashes' -- The crash occurred in *what followed* -- code you haven't provided. ===> **use a debugger** <===

Comment: @Jim Balter, I added the output of gdb. Could you help me to understand the debugger output information?

Comment: Don't...cast...return value...malloc...in C...

Comment: issue the command 'backtrace' and you'll see the program call chain.  Somewhere in there you'll recognize a function you (or a co-worker) wrote... start looking there.

Comment: Read gdb documentation to learn how to use it. Be sure to compile your program with -g. Then run your program under gdb; you will get a stack trace. That will tell you where in *your* program the crash happened. All that output you posted says is that it died in strtol_l, called from somewhere, because it was passed a NULL pointer.

Comment: In the backtrace, you'll see frame numbers (they're all sequential in the backtrace printout).  Issue 'frame #' (not the # symbol, but the actual frame number), then issue the command 'list'.  Assuming your build included debugging info including line numbers, you should see the line of source code that induced the crash, although the bug itself may not be on that line.

Comment: @EdS. It's unnecessary, but harmless (other than making the code more brittle). If it were being cast to the wrong type, there would be warnings.

Comment: @JimBalter: It's actually not harmless.  On some (older) compilers (i.e., VS which implements C89) casting the return value may hide the fact that you forgot to include `stdlib.h` because it will be assumed to return an `int`.. Really though, you shouldn't write unnecessary code, and it shows that the person who did it doesn't really understand how C treats pointer types

Comment: "the bug itself may not be on that line" -- right, but the code on that line will probably be passing a pointer that is NULL. It shouldn't be hard to figure out why.

Comment: casting `malloc` result is not a good idea in C, because it can disguise an undeclared `malloc` (which the compiler thinks is returning `int`)

Comment: @Jim Balter, gdb did not take my argument from the command line. Now I give the argument when I call the program in gdb, it gives another information. Sorry about the mistake!

Comment: @EdS. Ok, good point, I guess. Since the OP is using gcc, I would deal with that by asking gcc to warn about functions without prototypes.

Comment: @JimBalter: Yeah, it's not the end of the world, but I see it in just about every C code sample I see on forums.  I think they should at last understand why C is different than C++ in this regard.

Comment: `hamming_dist (ct=31 '\037', inter_value=203 '\313', ==> h=0x2 <==)` ... `*h = c` -- there's your problem.

Comment: @EdS. I did the casting mainly because g++ give me this error. cpa.cpp:195:42: warning: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘unsigned char**’ [-fpermissive]

Comment: Don't use g++ to compile C code.

Comment: @rex: Yep, as Jim said, you're using a C++ compiler

Comment: @rex: do ompile C as C, not as C++. I.e. use `gcc`, not `g++`.

Comment: @Jim Balter, gdb points to hamming_dist is a little confusing to me. Because I put a printf("rex\n"); before the hamming_dist function call and that never get printed. Please see my new edited source code.

Comment: Also. rename cpa.cpp to cpa.c ... unless it really is C++ code, in which case please change the tags. Meanwhile, I hope you're finding out why `h` is not a valid pointer.

Comment: Where did you initialize h? I'll bet you didn't.

Comment: "that never get printed" -- because -- ahem -- you never flushed it.

Comment: @Jim Balter, I flush it..forgot to add the line. Please see the added flush line. Still it did not print the rex.

Comment: @Ed S, A naive question, I dont quite understand the reason why g++ can't be used to compile c code..The reason why I use it is because i am calling functions that is written in c++.

Comment: I see no flush ... but it doesn't matter. You reach the call of hamming_dist, else gcc would not say you crashed in it. And gdb told you exactly what the problem is. Please read my answer and accept it once you have confirmed it.

Comment: @JimBalter, there is fflush in the loop right after I called the printf for inter_value

Comment: So what? There is no fflush between printing "rex" and calling hamming_dist. Go fix your bug; you have plenty of info now.

Comment: @rex: Because it is a C++ compiler.  You can write C in C++, but when write code which triggers some aspect wherein C and C++ differ you are going to have to abide by the C++ rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your seg fault is because `&h[j][i]` is 0x2 when passed as the value of the hamming_dist parameter h, which attempts to dereference it and store into it. This is apparently because of an earlier out-of-bounds store that overwrote `h[j]`.

Note that writing out of bounds in a malloced buffer can have effects that don't show up until arbitrarily later in your program. They may not show up at all ... until you release the code and some customer runs it with inputs that happen to trigger the bug.

Comment: I actually initialize h... Please see my Edit 6.

Comment: I also added the hamming_dist function definition.

Comment: Please stop with all these edits and just post the relevant parts of the program in order. The fact is that `&h[j][i]` has the value of 0x2 when it is passed to hamming_dist, which does `*h = c;`, which will cause a seg fault. Spend more time figuring out why and less time posting snippets to SO.

Comment: Thank you for the patient advice..This may sound too naive, but *h = c looks perfect to me..I am assigning a value to the pointer. Which works when my array size is small.

Comment: How can it look perfect to you when the value of h is ===> 2 <===? Please pay attention, as I have pointed this out numerous times now. It says so right here: `Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. 0x0804a3f5 in hamming_dist (ct=31 '\037', inter_value=203 '\313', h=0x2) at cpa.cpp:53` ... do you think that gdb is lying to you? Do you think that it cleverly figured out something that *would* cause a seg fault but isn't really happening in your program? The fact is that it is clear as day: h is 2, you try to store an int at location 2, it memfaults. Go fix it.

Comment: i rerun gdb, and then it gives me this new error information which points to this line. t[j][i] = h[j][i]; This line have an out of bound array access for t. I fixed it, now program runs!

Comment: Your out of bounds store probably overwrote h. My answer is still correct, so you should accept it, for all the effort I put in. And, if you had included the entire program, instead of just snippets, someone here would have seen that out of bounds store.

Comment: May I ask one last question? I use g++ to compile this code since it calls some other programs written in c++, since the code works...what is the main concern of using gcc to compile it? Thank you!

Comment: The concern is that they are different languages with sometimes subtle differences. Since you are using g++ and the file is called cpa.cpp, it is C++ code and this question should have had a C++ tag.

Comment: @rex See my edit about the problem of arbitrary effects from overwriting malloced memory. This is why you saw different symptoms, with it crashing in strtol_l earlier ... when you added printf calls, things changed and the bug moved around. That's a reason (among many) to use a debugger *instead* of printfs.

Comment: will use debugger in the future!